# How to test startActivity() call in onCreate()?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-espresso

I have an activity with the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (mUser.getLoggedInUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

So if a user is logged in, it should start `MainActivity` and finish immediately. I want to write a unit test to verify that MainActivity is actually launched. I've tried the following, using Espresso and `IntentsTestRule`:

```
@Test
public void testUserLoggedIn() {
    Intents.init();
    mUser = new User();
    mActivityRule.launchActivity(null);
    intended(hasComponent(MainActivity.class.getName()), times(1));
    Intents.release();
}
```

`mUser` is set via dependency injection, and the activity behaves as expected. However, the test fails with the following output:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000 cmp=global.snappy.android/.activities.onboarding.FirstStartActivity } within 45 seconds. Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time? There could be an animation or something constantly repainting the screen. Or the activity is doing network calls on creation? See the threaddump logs. For your reference the last time the event queue was idle before your activity launch request was 1486519735157 and now the last time the queue went idle was: 1486519735163. If these numbers are the same your activity might be hogging the event queue.
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:360)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.launchActivity(ActivityTestRule.java:219)
at global.snappy.android.activities.onboarding.FirstStartActivityTest.testUserLoggedIn(FirstStartActivityTest.java:108)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1886)
```

It seems the activity is closed before Espresso has time to attach for the test. Removing the `finish()` call in `onCreate()` does not change this. Is there any way to test this behaviour? Espresso would be preferable, but I can also use another framework if necessary.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not launching the same activity twice with `mActivityRule.launchActivity(null)`? Does your rule have false as a third constructor parameter?

Comment: Yes, `launchActivity` parameter is set to false: `new IntentsTestRule<>(FirstStartActivity.class, true, false)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`Spy`](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) class for your activity.
Then, you can check if `startActivity` was called with the `MainActivity` as parameter.

Test frameworks are good, but sometimes plain code looks better and it's more flexible.

Your Spy class would look like this (supposing your Activity name is `MyActivity`).

```
public class MyActivitySpy extends MyActivity {
  private boolean startActivityWasCalledToStartMainActivity;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public startActivity(Intent intent) {
   if(intentWithActivityName(intent, MainActivity.class.getSimpleName())) {
       startActivityWasCalledToStartMainActivity ;
    }
  }

  private boolean intentWithActivityName(Intent intent, String activityName) {
      activityName.equals(intent.getComponent().getClassName());
  }

  public boolean wasStartActivityCalledToStartMainActivity() {
      return startActivityWasCalledToStartMainActivity;
  }
}
```

Then, your test would be like.

```
@Test
public void testUserLoggedIn() {
    //launch MyActivitySpy instead of your real MyActivity
    assertTrue(myActivitySpy.wasStartActivityCalledToStartMainActivity());
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a great idea. Unfortunately, it fails because Android can't find the Activity. After adding the activity to `androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml`, it still fails to resolve the activity. Do you have any solution for this?